# Calculating error of MCMC algorithms?

Tags: self-study, markov-chain-montecarlo, algorithms

If for example the Transitional MCMC algorithm is used (or does it matter which one?), what are the common approaches for calculating an error (some sort of distance from the actual PDF), or validating that the samples drawn by the MCMC algorithm correspond to the PDF?

Maybe my question is wrongly formulated and uses wrong terms. I apologise for that since I am quite new to the area.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, by the nature of the problem, this is generally not possible. If you do know any feature of the distribution, like mean, mode(s), variance, etc, then it might be possible. But if the distribution is fully unknown, then you are never quite going to know if your code is right.

Comment: @Greenparker thanks! Do you have any resources I can check out for validation if certain features are known?

Comment: Well, the most obvious thing to do is compare the sample statistics to the truth. For example, if you know the true mean of the posterior, then you can compare the mean on the posterior samples to the true mean. If they are reasonably close, and as the number of MCMC samples increases, if you see the sample estimate converging to the truth, then you can be fairly certain your code is ok.